# Compare two objects and replace values with same key - keep/ignore the rest

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I am try merge two objects, but no really merge. I would like to only replace the values of the keys in common - ignore the rest.

```
obj1 = { a: 'replace a', b: 'keep b' }

obj2 = { a: 'new value a', c: 'ignore c' }
```

expected result:

```
console.log(obj1)       
// { a: 'new value a', b: 'keep b' }
```

I tried a couple different things like:

```
for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj2)) {
   obj1[k] = v
}
```

but not really what I was going for. And keep getting this Type error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type ... No index signature with a
> parameter of type 'string' was found on type ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate the keys of `obj2` and check if the key exists in `obj1`, then update with value.

```js
const
    obj1 = { a: 'replace a', b: 'keep b' },
    obj2 = { a: 'new value a', c: 'ignore c' };

for (const key in obj2) if (key in obj1) obj1[key] = obj2[key];

console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach.

```js
obj1 = { a: 'replace a', b: 'keep b' }

obj2 = { a: 'new value a', c: 'ignore c' }


newObj = {} 

for (const key in obj1) {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj1, key)) {
        const value  = obj1[key];
        newObj[ key  ]  = value;
        if( Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj2, key)  ){
         const value2  = obj2[key];
         newObj[ key  ]  = value2;
        }
        
        
    }
    
}

console.log( newObj )
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the object with the new values and update the values of the original object if the key is already present.

```js
const obj1 = { a: 'replace a', b: 'keep b' };
const obj2 = { a: 'new value a', c: 'ignore c' };

const mergeObjects = (obj1, obj2) => {
  // Create new object to prevent overwriting the original.
  const merged = Object.assign({}, obj1); 

  for (const key of Object.keys(obj2)) {
    if (key in merged) {
      merged[key] = obj2[key];
    }
  };
  
  return merged;
}

const result = mergeObjects(obj1, obj2);
console.log(result);
```